# Database name in oracle 12 connection parameters

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am currently working with MS SSIS to copy data from MSSQL to Oracle 12.
I cannot figure out how to make connection string to some test database.
I found sample connection string for oracle .net provider.

```
Data Source=
(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
        (ADDRESS=
            (PROTOCOL=TCP)
            (HOST=172.25.123.27)
            (PORT=1521)
        )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)
    )
)
DBA Privilege=SYSDBA
```

Where is the database name?
MSSQL has server, instance, user, password parameters.
What is "datasource" in this case?

Answer (score 0):

#### An Introduction

The equivalent of a SQL Server **database name** in Oracle would be a **schema**, but that won't help in this case, as you don't specify the **schema** in an Oracle connection string.

You would either use the `(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)` part to connect to an Oracle Database Instance (which in part corresponds to a SQL Server instance) or you would insert an alternate `(SID=<ORACLE_SID_on_server>)` just under the `(SERVICE_NAME...)` portion of the connection string.

An alternate solution is to use the other parameter `(GLOBAL_NAME=<ORACLE_SID_with_Domain>)` in the connection string.

But let's start from the beginning. When an Oracle Database Administrator installs an Oracle Database Instance, then they will generally define a name for that instance. The instance is created and contains a heap of internal tables/views and other data dictionary objects. This corresponds to the SQL Server instance (in most cases).

After the initial setup, developers will create schemas and load (user/schema) objects into the newly created schema. The developers will then decide what `GRANT`s to assign to individual logins (users). This is what corresponds to a SQL Server database (in most cases).

When using a connection string, you are actually connecting to an Oracle Database Instance (in most cases). The login / user you use to initiate the connection will determine what you see in the database instance (e.g. which user schemas).

#### Answering Your Questions

> **Where is the database name?**

In your case the `SERVICE_NAME` is the parameter you are looking for. This is the name of the Oracle Database Instance. In your case `orcl`. However, this could be just a default value. Ask your Oracle DBA for the correct name of the Oracle Database Instance on your server with the IP address `172.25.123.27`.

You could alternatively supply the following parameters:

```
        (SID=orcl)
        (GLOBAL_NAME=orcl.domain.tld)
```

These parameters have to match the defined parameters of the Oracle Database instance. Ask your Oracle DBA for this information.

> **MSSQL has server, instance, user, password parameters.**

See my explanation above.

> **What is "datasource" in this case?**

**Data Source** is normally the name you give to the defined connection string. It can be compared to a CNAME / Alias in DNS terms. It's just a name you can give to the portion of the connection string you are defining. I name the following example `OR19PROD` and added the  `SID` and `GLOBAL_NAME` parameters for your convenience.

```
OR19PROD=
(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
        (ADDRESS=
            (PROTOCOL=TCP)
            (HOST=172.25.123.27)
            (PORT=1521)
        )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)
        (SID=orcl)
        (GLOBAL_NAME=orcl.domain.com)
    )
)
```

A user could now connect to the `OR19PROD` alias (TNSNAME.ora entry) which would redirect to the correct server.

#### Reference Reading

- [Local Naming Parameters in the tnsnames.ora File](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tns-ora-file.html#GUID-7F967CE5-5498-427C-9390-4A5C6767ADAA) (Oracle Docs)